# CORS issue with xhr resource download request

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

```html
xhr.open('GET', 'url/url_filePath=mydownload.zip', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    let that = this;
    
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        let data = this.response;
        const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        const file = new File([blob], 'mydownload.zip', {type: 'application/zip'});
        that.han
        that.setState((prevState, props) => {
          return {
            install : false
          };
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

I have the above lines of code to download and upload a zip file. I get an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header not present error each time I try an make the request to download. I countered this with a chrome extension that handles this but I need a scaleable solution that will not require the chrome extension. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have control of the server you're trying to download from? You can't defeat this client side in a manner that scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS headers sent by the server basically state which origins are allowed to request resources from that particular server. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and Fetch
>   follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using
>   XMLHttpRequest or Fetch could only make HTTP requests to its own
>   domain.

To allow your web application to fetch resources from that origin, the server **must** send a CORS header.

The format should follow: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`.

Comment: looks like a relative url to me

Comment: If its a relative URL, there should be no issues with CORS though. No same origin violation there.

Comment: @Carey The url is not relative. I am trying to download a resource from bintray from my local host, then upload the same resource to my server.

Comment: Bintray does not provide a permissive CORS policy; you must download the file on your server itself. This question is also addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558862/how-to-get-latest-version-of-a-artifact-on-bintray-using-jsonp

Comment: @Carey Is it possible to set these request headers while I make the request? Or is there a way to enable CORS on my server?

Comment: CORS is **entirely** server side. You don't control bintray, so no you cannot enable these headers. A possible workaround is to setup your own server to download these files for you, and then forward them on to the client, although this approach seems relatively pointless in your scenario.